# How to return AWS error status from a Node.JS / Express.JS post() method?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using Ajax to call a NodeJS / ExpressJS post method that itself calls AWS, and I want the AWS return status to be returned back to the browser. Not surprisingly, the   “res.status(200).send('Success!');” at the end of the snippet below is called before AWS itself is even called, hence is meaningless.  But can’t figure out how to get to the original Ajax “res” object in the anonymous return function from AWS, so I can call .status and .send on it.  Seems straightforward, but haven’t been able to figure it out.

```
router.post('/notification', function(req, res) {
    var config = req.app.get('config');
    var sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: config.AWS_REGION});
    var snsMessage = 'Hello world!';
    sns.publish({ TopicArn: config.NEW_SIGNUP_TOPIC, 
                  Message: snsMessage }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error publishing SNS message: ' + err);
        } else {
            // How to get the original res object here, so I can call 
            // res.status(200).send('It worked!') here  
            console.log('It worked!');
        }
    });
    // The following line returns status to the original ajax post call 
    // before AWS is even called.  
    res.status(200).send('Success!');  // 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just move that line of code into the callback? Something like this:

```
router.post('/notification', function(req, res) {
    var config = req.app.get('config');
    var sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: config.AWS_REGION});
    var snsMessage = 'Hello world!';
    sns.publish({ TopicArn: config.NEW_SIGNUP_TOPIC, 
                  Message: snsMessage }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error publishing SNS message: ' + err);

            res.status(500).send('Error!');
        } else {
            // How to get the original res object here, so I can call 
            // res.status(200).send('It worked!') here  
            console.log('It worked!');

            res.status(200).send('Success!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that worked!  Who knew!  I'm surprised that the scope of "res" could extend to the anonymous callback function executed later, but I guess Javascript understands that it's accessing an object in the calling method and makes it work.   Thanks so much!

Comment: For fun, I just tried creating a local variable foo in router.post(), and as expected I got an error when trying to access foo in the callback.  I guess I'm counting on the fact that the original request object hasn't gone anywhere, and hence the callback can still get to it?  Thoughts?

Comment: You should read up on javascript scopes. Show your new code if you have a new issue. Or ask it as a new question.

Comment: From your reply, I'm guessing that the response object has global scope, hence the reason why it's still available.  All set for now.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's not global, it's just in scope. I'm not sure how you got that it is global from my reply. You said you ran a test that didn't work, but it sounds to me like it should have worked, so like I said, if you want more help with that test or something else you need to show the exact code. I think you are making assumptions about JavaScript scopes based on your knowledge of how variable scopes work in a different programming language, when you need to take the time to read up on how JavaScript scopes work. I don't really know how to condense a tutorial on JS scopes into an answer on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Route middleware takes an optional third parameter `next` that can be used to pass errors to the applications global error handler.

```
router.post('/notification', function(req, res, next) {
...
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error publishing SNS message: ' + err);
        next(err);
    } else {
        // How to get the original res object here, so I can call 
        // res.status(200).send('It worked!') here  
        console.log('It worked!');
        res.status(200).send('Success!');
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Indeed it appears you can access the res object directly from the callback, which appears to do the trick.